# how to iterate using iterrows() and check for a subset

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, hashable

I would find the rows in a dataframe which contains all of the elements of a tuple and then set a value in a specific column for the corrisponding index of the row

```
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if set(tuple).issubset(row):
      df.loc[ix, ['label']] = 1
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

if I perform the following chunk of code it seems that it works but I don't know how to set the value in the label column where the row match the tuple

```
for row in df.astype(str).values.tolist():
  set(tuple).issubset(row))
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you give more detail about the dataframe ? do you mean you are giving a tuple and searching for it in a two column dataframe

Comment: My dataframe has many columns.
I have to find the line containing all the elements of the tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and `iloc`.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(df.astype(str).values.tolist()):
    if set(tuple).issubset(row):
        df.iloc[idx, df.columns.get_loc('label')] = 1
```

Comment: thank you!! ..  
I have find also this solution that it works: 
`for ix, row in df.astype(str).iterrows():     
 if set(tuple).issubset(row):
  df.loc[ix, ['label']] = 1` 
but I don't understand very well why

Comment: ```iterrows``` returns a tuple of the index (here, ix) and the row values (here, row). So you can set the value of a row by df.loc[ix].

Comment: Thanks again.. but what I exactly don't understand is why the loop works with `df.astype(str).iterrows()` and not with `df.iterrrows()`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension for example with random generated data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2)

tuples = list(zip(np.random.randint(0, 5, 10), np.random.randint(
    10, 15, 10), np.random.randint(20, 30, 10)))

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(tups=tuples))

data.head()

#   tups
# 0 (0, 14, 23)
# 1 (0, 14, 25)
# 2 (3, 14, 28)
```

Then you can set `label` generating the values from the list comphrension

```
tuple_subset = (0, 14)
data['Label'] = [1 if set(tuple_subset).issubset(x)
                 else None for x in data.tups]

data.head(3)

#   tups        Label
# 0 (0, 14, 23) 1.0
# 1 (0, 14, 25) 1.0
# 2 (3, 14, 28) NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution but I don't know how to use list comprehension with all the values of all the columns at the same time (iterating one row at a time).